# Why do I get null for Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR and Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR?

Tags: android, sensors

I have a Yureka phone, and [from its specs](http://www.amazon.in/yu) I can see that it has at least an accelerometer and a gyroscope.

What I found from the net is that `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` needs accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer. Since I do not have magnetometer, maybe because of that I am unable to get this sensor.

However, from [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR) it looks like `TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` does not need magnetometer, then why am I also not getting this sensor?

I am trying to use this sensor to measure the tilt angle, with respect to ground, of the phone screen when the user is trying to hold it flat on his hands.

Comment: It is not clear that the Yureka phone has accelerometer. In [this](http://micromaxcanvas.co.in/mmx-yu-yureka-xiaomi-redmi-note/) website, you can see that the accelerometer is not present in the Yureka Phone specs. Just a guess.

Comment: @RodolfoPerottoni Actually the specs mentions G-Sensor, which according to Yahoo Answers is Accelerometer. In fact I also install Androsensor app and it too confirmed that.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try to use the code below to print out the information of all the sensors on your device. If the sensor is not printed out, it's not available.

```
List<Sensor> deviceSensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
for(int i=0; i<gravSensors.size(); i++) {
    // print out sensors information
}
```

Then, even if you have an accelerometer and a gyroscope, the TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR might still not be supported. That's because it's a software sensor, and is derived from the data from other sensors by the Android system. There might be other factors that decides the availability of the software sensor, e.g. frequency, energy consumption, reliability. In that way, you might need to derive the other values yourself using the raw data you can get from the sensors.

Hope this helps!